# How can I make permanent permissions for a directory using chmod?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I want all the new files I create in the directory to have specific permissions, but whenever I create a new file in the directory, it gets the default system permissions even though I used chmod -R before. Is there any way to make my permissions stick for all new files and folders I create in the subdirectory?

Comment: new files are set by umask not chmod - see http://linux.die.net/man/2/umask

Answer (score 1):

- `sudo mkdir --mode=define_permissions dir_name`
- `sudo chown user_name dir_name`
- `touch dir_name/file_name`

If this does not work for you, try using ACls.